# display splash page on webpage load - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i search lot, but unable to get code how to display splash on page load.

take website as samaple.

```
groupon  co uk
```

want simple example

many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load splash screen from following code(You need to include JQuery)

```
window.onload = function() {
    $("#yourSplashScreenId").show();
    };
```